# browser.windows.create throws error on EDGE extension

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I have written the following code in the background.js file of an EDGE Extension:

```
browser.windows.create({"url": request.openUrlInEditor, "incognito": true});
```

It throws error saying 'incognito' property is not recognized/undefined. If I remove the  'incognito' property then it works - opens the window but not in private mode.
As per the [MDN API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create) the 'incognito' property is suppose to work on EDGE. It is working with Firefox browser tho.

Comment: Microsoft team was able to confirm the issue but no fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 10 machine build (**17134.77**) the following syntax works perfectly well:

browser.windows.create({"url": "https://www.example.com", "incognito": true});

However if you are on an older build please check the following syntax:

browser.windows.create({"url": "https://www.example.com", "**inprivate**": true});

Microsoft has changed the property from inprivate to incognito recently

Comment: @Rahatur I tried it out in the console of background page.

Comment: Does it work if you put the code in the background page instead of console?

Comment: @Rahatur I think you are confused. There is a background page running if you have specified background key in the manifest file. When you go to edge actions pane > Extensions > "Your extension". On your extension' s details page you will have an option to inspect background page. When you click this you'll see a F12 Developer window show up. Now in this window there will be a console tab. I have tried the above code in this console